# WebView with Charles (iOS9)

Tags: webview, ios9, charles-proxy

I tried to use Charles for WebView testing, but got an error:

> SSLHandshake: Remote host closed connection during handshake.

The .plist already contains this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Method: CONNECT

Protocol: HTTP/1.0

Does anybody faced with the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Charles SSL certificate to see decoded message.

Check this post for how to install SSL certificate.

http://go4test.blogspot.ca/2016/10/install-ssl-certificate-on-iphone-or.html